# Create BitLocker container and save the password for user not computer

Tags: windows-7, encryption, bitlocker

I can create a BitLocker container and connect it as a drive. Then I can encrypt that container with BitLocker and then I have the possibility to save the password for a computer. So that means anybody that is logged on that computer, does not need to know the passwort.

Because the container, in my case, is user specific I don’t want to save the password for computer, but for user. So when the user logs in, he don't need to type the password. But if another user logs in, he doesn’t see that drive or he must type the password.

Is this possible?

Comment: sorry, in german we have passwort ;)